# How to exclude google apis from Jmter mobile recording?

Tags: jmeter, apk, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

When i'm trying to record a Jmeter script from a mobile app, as soon as i connect my mobile Jmeter starts recording below requests continuously.

```
www.google.com/gen_204`play.googleapis.com/generate_204`connectivitycheck.gstatic.com`
```

I have tried excluding these URLs from request filtering. Under URL patterns to exclude i have below URLs mentioned

```
^((?!google).)*$`www.google.com/gen_204`play.googleapis.com/generate_204`http://www.google.com/gen_204`play\.googleapis\.com`connectivitycheck\.gstatic\.com`
```

But still Jmeter is recording these requests continuously.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following regular expressions to "URL Patterns to Exclude" input field under **Requests Filtering** tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

```
.*google\.com.*
.*play\.googleapis\.com.*
.*connectivitycheck\.gstatic\.com.*
```

and so on for every domain you want to exclude from the recording scope.

[image]

Just remember to escape [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) with a backslash

More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)